# Delphi Inline Changes Answer to Bit Reading

Tags: delphi, bit

I'm using Delphi Berlin with default compiler options. I'm doing some bit routines and have a case that where inline changes the answer.

My code:

```
function BitGetFromQWord( const AQWord: UInt64; ABitIdx: UInt64 ): Boolean; //inline;
begin
  Assert( ABitIdx<64 );
  Result := ((1 shl ABitIdx) and AQWord)<>0;
end;

procedure TForm22.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage( BoolToStr( BitGetFromQWord( $CBBE02D50FD8262F, 31 ), True ) );
end;

procedure TForm22.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: Integer;
begin
  x := 31;
  ShowMessage( BoolToStr( BitGetFromQWord( $CBBE02D50FD8262F, x ), True ) );
end;
```

For Button1Click, the answer changes from False (which looks correct) to True when inline is added. My table below is:

[image: True/False Table]

Button2Click, which just replaces the constant with a variable, always yields False.

I was running a large amount of bit checking and setting and came across this anomaly. That why the random hex number is here.

I also have a case with the same hex number and bit 31 in a larger project that yields different results based upon Debug or Release. Unable to simplify that yet to a reasonable example.

The code looks correct. I found a similar function for 32-bits here:

[Bit Manipulation Using Delphi](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2009/10/21/bits-manipulation-functions-using-delphi/)

So my question is why would the inline word change the answer?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembler code?

Comment: Not yet. Truthfully, even if it was different, I wouldn't have known what to fix, just that it's different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is wrong in because the bitwise shift is performed in a 32 bit context. You must write it like this

```
Result := ((UInt64(1) shl ABitIdx) and AQWord)<>0;
```

where the cast forces 64 bit arithmetic.

So whilst it seems wrong that the inlined version of the code behaves differently from the non-inlined version, I suspect that the real issue is that your code's behaviour is ill-defined. Once you fix the code, as shown above, you will find that the inlined and non-inlined versions behave the same, and give the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll give that a try. I still don't quite get why it's a 32-bit context when ABitIdx is a UInt64? Having the answer switch when inlining or switching to a release version is pretty touchy though. Definitely requires extra care and feeding. :-)

Comment: `ABitInd` must be less than 64 so no point at all in wasting a 64 bit type on it. What counts is the type of the lhs of the expression, the literal `1` in your code

Comment: Also, curious: Why does the Button2Click work if it's passed as a 32-bit integer instead of a constant?

Comment: I don't really know. Chance? I think it's ill defined. Very possibly a bug. But one that disappears when you fix the bug in your code

Comment: Agreed that a 64-bit type is a waste. That was the attempt to get it to a 64-bit context. >>What counts is the type of the lhs of the expression, the literal 1 in your code. Could you enlighten me on "lhs"?

Comment: lhs is left hand side